# Bidirectional Sync of iPhone/iDevice Photos and Albums to Third Party Clouds

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, photos, photo-stream

It is a complete mystery to me why this challenge has not been dealt with and solved, and why not more people are complaining about it on the web:

I use my iPhone as my main camera. I use it to snap photos and subsequently sort them into albums on my phone. I also have an iPad and a PC laptop, but do not use the latter frequently to edit photos.

What I (and I assume many other people out there) would like, is a simple functionality on  your iDevice (iPhone/iPad/etc) that basically two-way syncs pictures and albums between all devices. So, when I take a picture on my iPhone or iPad it should automatically be sent to a cloud (SugarSync, Google Drive, Dropbox, a private cloud, or similar) and from there be reflected on all my devices. Similarly, if I delete or modify a photo on one of my devices, that change should be reflected automatically on all the other devices.

With most paid-for clouds (such as SugarSync and Dropbox), you have one-way synching functionality of pictures. So when you take a photo, it is backed up to the drive. Sadly, it is not bidirectional, so if I delete a photo on one device, it is not reflected on the other devices.

As for Photo Stream and iCloud the problems are as follows.

1. It does not sync the albums you create on your device.
2. You actually have to open iPhoto and make sure the images are imported to your computer, to avoid that they get deleted after the 30 day photo stream period is up.
3. You are stuck with iCloud, so if you decide to buy an Android phone, you will encounter a road block.

Anyone have any information or thoughts on how to tackle this challenge? One thought would be to just use an alternative Camera and Photo app on the iPhone, that works with other clouds than iCloud. If you know of any such tools, please shout out.

Comment: This is now possible with iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: Did you find any resaonable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Unbound app](http://unboundapp.com/). It uses dropbox to allow you to organize your photos on your ipad. So you can move, delete and rename photos on your iPad and the changes are synced back to your dropbox.

I tried it and liked it, but I don't use it, because all the managing functions (move, delete, rename) only work, when you are online.

Comment: The OP wrote ***PC laptop***